# Internal anchor links break scrollbar with Tiny Scrollbar plugin

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, anchor

Help! I'm trying to build a webpage using the excellent [Tiny Scrollbar](http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) from www.baijs.nl. However, i need to add some internal anchor links to jump down to the appropriate section of the content but this is proving to be a problem. (All the content, including the internal anchor links, are housed within the Tiny Scrollbar div containers).

See my basic mockup on http://jsfiddle.net/uy4hK/

My problem is that although the internal link is jumping down to the correct section, the scrollbar on the right is not updating to the correct position - it just stays at the top. There is an update method that can be used, and the demo also has a version of internal scrolling but using a number variable (200px) but i am unable to tweak this to make it work in my jsfiddle demo. I can't really use a number because content can vary and the internal links are within the content inside the Tiny Scrollbar container.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/fausak/uy4hK/2/

I think you can pull this off with use of jQuery's [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) method. Try this:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
    // Find the bottom of the box with the scrollbar
    // (close approximation: the top position of the last element in the box)
    var bottom = $('.viewport .overview').children().last().position().top;

    // Determine what position this internal link is located at
    // (if you use <a name=".."> you will need to change this,
    // right now it only matches element IDs like <h1 id="link0">
    var cur = $($(this).attr('href')).position().top;

    // If the position of the link is too low for the scrollbar in this box,
    // just set it to the bottom
    if (cur >= bottom - $('.viewport').height()) {
        cur = 'bottom';
    }
    else {
        cur = cur + 'px';
    }

    $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar_update(cur);
});
```

Comment: Hi rfausak, not sure how you did it but your answer seems to work fine so thank you very much! Its jumping to the appropriate sub section and the scrollbar is also updating too, this is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks rfausak.

Actually in situation, we want to make anchor link external from scrollbar. We can make for example :

```
<div class="overview">
  <h3 id="link0">Magnis dis parturient montes</h3>
    <p>Text in here</p>
  <h3 id="link1">Magnis dis parturient montes</h3>
    <p>Text in here</p>
</div>



<a href="#" rel="link1" class="scroll1load">anchor link1</a>
<a href="#" rel="link0" class="scroll1load">anchor link0</a>
```

Modifying of rfausak code:

```
$('a.scroll1load').click(function(){
            // Find the bottom of the box with the scrollbar
            // (close approximation: the top position of the last element in the box)
            var bottom = $('.viewport .overview').children().last().position().top;

            // Determine what position this internal link is located at
            // (if you use <a name=".."> you will need to change this,
            // right now it only matches element IDs like <h1 id="link0">
            //var cur = $($('#scroll1load').attr('href')).position().top;
            var anchor =  $(this).attr('rel');
            var cur = $('div.overview h3#'+anchor).position().top;
            // If the position of the link is too low for the scrollbar in this box,
            // just set it to the bottom
            if (cur >= bottom - $('.viewport').height()) {
                cur = 'bottom';
            }
            else {
                cur = cur + 'px';
            }



            oScroll.tinyscrollbar_update(cur);
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if exactly what you're asking is possible with the Tiny Scrollbar plugin. The following will get you pretty close, though:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
    $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar_update('bottom');
});
```

If your content is static, you could replace `'bottom'` with an actual pixel length, like `'25px'`.

Comment: But different links could be at different places in the page, hence this is not a flexible solution. He would have to hard code the position of each link.

Comment: That's what I was trying to imply.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick reply. Got a feeling this may not work for me - content and internal links can vary - but let me try your suggestion. Just wonderingnany other solutions or hacks?

Comment: Yeah actually I think I figured it out, I'll post another answer in a minute.